# Hierarchical Model View Controller Test on CodeIgniter 3.04

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to test HVMC (Hierarchical Model View Controller) on CodeIgniter 3.04, and received this error:

> Fatal error: Access level to MX_Router::_set_default_controller() must be public (as in class CI_Router) in C:\xampp\htdocs\hmvctest\application\third_party\MX\Router.php on line 245

How do I resolve it?

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Show some codes or follow this http://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: Please include the code throwing the error _in the question itself_.